# ActionbarSherlock - How to set shadow for actionbar MenuItem Text?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

is there any way to set shadow for actionbar menuitem text using actionbarsherlock? i have already tried to set shadow for actionbar menuitem text not yet working . thanks in advance